# Can't call future::get on a future stored in a map

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I am storing C++ futures in a map, but then I can't call `future::get()` on the futures once they are in the map.

Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int my_func(int x) {
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    map<int, future<int>> tasks;

    // Create a task and add it to the map
    int job_no = 0;
    tasks.insert(make_pair(job_no, async(&my_func, job_no)) );

    // See if the job has finished
    for (auto it = tasks.cbegin(); it != tasks.cend(); ) {
        auto job = it->first;
        auto status = (it->second).wait_for(chrono::seconds(5));

        if (status == future_status::ready) {
           int val = (it->second).get();  /* This won't compile */
           cout << "Job " << job << " has finished with value: " << val << "\n";
           it = tasks.erase(it);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
test.cc:26:39: error: passing ‘const std::future<int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
            int val = (it->second).get();  /* This won't compile */
                                       ^
In file included from test.cc:4:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/future:793:7: note:   in call to ‘_Res std::future<_Res>::get() [with _Res = int]’
       get()
```

I think this has something to do with futures not being callable (eg. see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346722/stdmove-on-a-stdfuture-stored-in-a-pair) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126551/storing-a-future-in-a-list)), but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you are using *const-iterator* while iterating your map, then you can only read value of map (you can call *const* memebers on `future`). But you are calling `get` on future objects, and you get errors because `get` is non-const qualified member of `future` class. So try

```
for (auto it = tasks.begin(); it != tasks.end(); ) {
```